# Investigate on the convergence of the series, with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{[n^a]}n^{-a}$$ 
Learn for what $a \in \mathbb {R}$ **sequence converges**. Symbol *[x]* means integer part (floor?) of number *x*.
It's my first question, if you will haveany complaints - write about it please.

Comment: Woah, interesting problem. For starters, it is trivial that the sequence converges for $a\ge 1$ using standard convergence tests.

Comment: This suggests another very interesting question: does there exist $a\in (0,1)$ such that $[n^a]$ is even for all natural $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This series converges if and only if $a > \frac12$.

Let's deal with the easy parts first:

1. It is absolutely convergent for $a > 1$, this is well known.
2. It diverges for $a \le 0$, as the terms do not go to zero.
3. Now, for the important part, $0 < a \le 1$, the idea is to group the terms together for which $\lfloor n^a\rfloor$ is the same:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{\lfloor n^a\rfloor}n^{-a} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x_k \text{ where } x_k = \sum_{\lfloor n^a\rfloor=k} n^{-a} = \sum_{k^{1/a} \le n < (k+1)^{1/a}} n^{-a}$$

So, the original series is equivalent to a sign-alternating series: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x_k$. Let's look at $x_k$ more closely:

$$ x_k = \sum_{\lfloor n^a\rfloor=k} n^{-a} = \sum_{\lfloor n^a\rfloor=k} \left(\frac{1}{k} + O(\frac1{k^2})\right) = \left((k+1)^{1/a} - k^{1/a} + O(1)\right)\left(\frac{1}{k} + O(\frac1{k^2})\right) = k^{1/a}\left(\frac1{ak} + O(\frac1{k^2})\right)\left(\frac{1}{k} + O(\frac1{k^2})\right) = \frac{k^{\frac1a - 2}}{a} + O(k^{\frac1a -3}) $$

From which we can easily see that:

4. If $a \le \frac12$ then $\frac1a -2 \ge 0$ and $\lim x_k \ne 0$, so the series diverges.
5. If $a > \frac 12$ then $\frac1a -2 < 0$ and $\frac1a -3 < -1$, so

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x_k = \frac1a \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^kk^{\frac1a -2} + \sum_k O(k^{\frac1a -3})$$

Because the second part absolutely converges. And the first part converges because it's a sign-alternating series with terms going to zero monotonously.

Comment: +1 (note that it's similar, and generalizes, by answer which did the same but for $a=1/2$ only)

Comment: @klao Wow, brilliant! You solved it! :D (+1)

Comment: @Frpzzd **I** didn't. I dealt with a specific case, klao gave the suitable generalization, thus fully answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

*A quick answer showing divergence for $a=1/2$.*

For $N\geq 1$, on can write the partial sum $S_{N^2}$ as
$$S_{N^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{N^2} \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^k \sum_{\ell=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\ell}}\,.$$
Now, since
$$\sum_{\ell=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\ell}} = 2 + \frac{1}{2k^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$ when $k\to\infty$, and recalling that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{2k^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right)$ is absolutely convergent, we get that $(S_{N^2})_N$ converges is, and only if, $2\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k$ does. And it does not.

---

Here is a plot illustrating the (lack of) convergence, for $a=1/2$ (for partial sums $S_n$ up to $n=2000$).

[image]